# how to show p:dialog in a template, after logging in, depending on a boolean in the user?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

im kinda new to JEE. I use Eclipse, Glassfish, JSF, Primefaces and Ajax.

Im trying to show a Change-Password-Dialog after logging in, depending on a boolean, which defines whether a password-change is required or not.

The password change-dialog is in a header template, its a primafaces dialog and is currently opened when the user presses a change-password-symbol in the header (`<p:commandLink id="btn_pwdChange" onclick="PF('ctr_dlgPwdChange').show();"...`)

My current idea is to use the visible-attribute of p:dialog to show it depending of my changePasswordOnNextLogin-Boolean in the user.

Are there other ways to solve this problem? I was assigned to find different solutions, in order to choose the best out of it later with the team. But so far i cant find any other solution. I thought about some kind of event handling in the onload of the template, but i cant find anything in this direction. I excluded JSF since its server-sided and i need to show the dialog on the client side. Are there even other ways? I have not a single idea left what else to try, but it feels like im overlooking something

Comment: Off-topic: These are not the sort of questions for Stackoverflow..

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of other ways to solve it, all more complex and hacky than using the `visible` attribute. So stick with that. Remarkable that you need to spend time finding other solutions when the best is already there